# How do I Display a Custom Error Message in Bundle

Tags: error-handling, wix, 32bit-64bit, bootstrapper

I am working on a **bootstrapper** project that when run, **installs** a `32bit` or `64bit` driver depending on the architecture the installed program is.

I would like to display an **error message**, prevent installation and close the application if there is **no** `32bit` or `64bit` program installed on the machine.

This is what I have but the `<Condition>` is causing an **invalid child element error**. Perhaps I cannot use a condition in the chain but is there a way I could do this very simply or will I need to create an `<ExePackage>`?

```
<Bundle...      
    <!-- Define variables -->
    <Variable Name="ErrorMessage" Type="string" Value="Neither the 32-bit nor the 64-bit program is installed." />
      
    <!-- Registry searches -->      
    ...
    <Chain>

        <MsiPackages...    
    
         <Condition Message="[ErrorMessage]">
          <![CDATA[NOT ProgramInstalled32 AND NOT ProgramInstalled64]]>
        </Condition>
    
    </Chain>
</Bundle>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working! After some research on the `Condition` tag and how it works I realized the approach I had was wrong because the **MsiPackage** will not install if the `Condition` returns false.

This is my solution, I put it just under the chain:

```
  <bal:Condition Message="The Product is not installed.">
        (ProgramInstalled32 = 1) OR (ProgramInstalled64 = 1)
  </bal:Condition>
```

I tested it and when I ran the `.EXE` it installed the `64bit` driver as I have the `64bit` program installed. And when I uninstalled the program, then ran the `.EXE`, the error
message displayed and prevented the installation. Hope this works for you!